# How to create Combobox with multiselect capability?

Tags: jquery-ui

How to create a Combobox having Multiselect Capability using Jquery?
Does JQuery Combobox has this functionality or Property?

Answer (score 2):

if it helps, take a look http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/ for multi select values

Edited : I found one more link it's really great http://tameraydin.github.io/jquery-easyselect/

[image: Screen shot of jQuery easy select]

Answer (score 1):

Combobox displays the selected value when its list of options is collapsed. You may want to use [multiple selection list](http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/forms/_SELECT_MULTIPLE.html).

Comment: Yes i want to select multiple values from Combo box. How can i do this.

Comment: Click on the link. There's a tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

to use multiple select in combobox  you will have to create your own user control using checked listbox, textbox and a button. 
and on click of button just make checked list box visible and let the user select items from that checkedListBox and as user select items on it you take those values and concatenate it in textbox with comma seperated. and then again on click on button hide that list box.

as it is on : http://9perhour.co.uk/
which is asking for select technology

some good samples 
for jquery:

http://abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/04/jquery-multiselect/

http://quasipartikel.at/multiselect/

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/ajax/jqueryajax.aspx

for asp.net:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/user-controls/MultipleSelectionDropDown.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/DataGridDropDownList.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/asp/multiselectdropdown.aspx

Comment: Actually i want to implement it with Asp.Net MVC 2. But here i am trying to use JQuery because it might be available in JQuery.